# Generated C++ code using MATLAB Coder : Compilation Error "undefined reference to `rgb2gray_tbb_real64'"

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-coder

Generated C++ code from MATLAB for converting an image to grayscale, using MATLAB Coder. While compiling it on Dev C++ it shows error- `undefined reference to rgb2gray_tbb_real64`

One of the Generated code uses header file `libmwrgb2gray_tbb.h`. [Screenschot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF5Vy.png) It calls a function `rgb2gray_tbb_real64`, which is not defined anywhere.

How to sort this out?

Comment: Please don't post images of code and error messages. Instead, copy-paste them into your question. Images are not searchable, and not easy (or impossible) to read for people with visual disabilities.

Comment: Regarding your question: did you follow the instructions in Coder related to linking in the appropriate libraries? It looks like a library needs to be linked in.

Answer (score 2):

Image Processing Toolbox code generation supports 2 distinct modes:

1. Generated code uses platform-specific optimized shared libraries. This is enabled for the MATLAB Coder hardware target `MATLAB Host Computer` and a few other similar targets.
2. Generated code is standalone, independent of shared libraries, and portable

The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/understanding-code-generation-with-image-processing-toolbox.html) covers these concepts in more detail. When using option (1), you must package the generated code using Coder utilities in order to relocate it. MATLAB Coder knows how to properly gather and package all of the dependencies for your generated code.

To do this packaging, you can use the `packNGo` function, use the `Package` button on the `Finish Workflow` screen of the MATLAB Coder App, or the `Package Code` button in the MATLAB Coder report. These steps are detailed in the [MATLAB Coder documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/package-code-for-other-development-environments.html). To use `packNGo` you can:

```matlab
codegen myFunction -args {1,2,3} -config:lib -report
load(fullfile('codegen','lib','myFunction','buildInfo.mat'));
packNGo(buildInfo, 'fileName', 'myFunction.zip');
```

That will create `myFunction.zip` in your current directory which will contain your generated code and all of the headers and libraries on which it depends. You can then import all of those into your IDE of choice.